# Loot all from chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I consequently happened to have all items from a chest moved to my inventory while I was quickly <kbd>Shift</kbd> clicking them. It really looked like a Loot-all hidden feature being activated.

Similarly, once all items hoped from hot-bar to my inventory - again during  <kbd>Shift</kbd> clicking.

So far, I haven't played multiplayer to see if it happens on bukkit as well.

The [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Inventory) doesn't say anything about such a feature.

Is that a bug? If not, how do I trigger it intentionally?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well there is currently no such feature that allows you to move all items of **different types** from your chest to inventory. At least, in vanilla Minecraft.

However, there could be a reason for this "phenomenon" occurring. Accoding to the [Minecraft wiki on inventory](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Inventory#Managing_inventory), it states that:

> To move all items of one kind into a chest from your inventory (and
> vice versa), pick up any item, hold ⇧ Shift, and double click one of
> the items (or a stack) of the items you want to move.

In addition, it states in the [Minecraft wiki for Chests](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chest#Filling):

> By holding ⇧ Shift and double-clicking while holding an item, all
> items of a type clicked on will be moved into or out of the chest.

To put this into a scenario, if you have a chest entirely filled with **ONLY** iron ingots, **ALL** the iron ingots will be transferred to your inventory is you were to ⇧ Shift and double-click one of the **IRON INGOT STACKS**.

However, if there were blocks of sand mixed up with the ingots, and you were to ⇧ Shift and double-click a stack of **IRON INGOTS**, all the iron ingots and ONLY the iron ingots will move into your inventory, leaving the sand behind.

Comment: Breaking the chest also works.

Comment: Hey Marge, I just tripled my productivity!

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: I don't think this works with enchanted gear; however, this does work with 1.14.2.